# Java Sending data through a socket - why do I need to put a newline at the end of a String?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

So, while I now get why the Outputstream connected to a socket needs to be flushed when data should be sent immediately, I still don't get why I need to put a newline at the end of the String.

This works:

```
// writer is a PrintWriter
writer.println("Hello World!");
```

This doesn't:

```
Writer.print("Hello World!");
writer.flush;
```

Comment: Did you just forget the () at writer.flush or is this real code? If it's real code, try it with writer.flush();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define *work* and *doesn't work* more precisely. What's the protocol between the client and the server? What do you expect to happen and what do you observe?

I suspect the server is simply waiting for a newline character to appear in its input before doing anything. If that's the case, then of course flushing the writer at client side before sending the newline won't help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading with a BufferedReaders readLine method as per your previous question, readLine won't complete unless it finds the newline character(s).